# Why is $\frac{1}{\pi ^{1/4} \sqrt{a}}e^{-x^2/(2a^2)}$ not a gaussian function?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, perturbation-theory, gaussian

In an quantum mechanics exercise, we were asked to find the ground-state wavefunction of a perturbed harmonic system. The resulting wave-function is $$\psi_0(x) = \frac{1}{\pi ^{1/4} \sqrt{a}}e^{-x^2/(2a^2)}$$

After that, there is a true or false statement:

The ground-state wave function of the perturbed system
is a gaussian. -> False.

May I ask you why this is not a gaussian ? When looking on Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_function , this seems to be a gaussian for me.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Aside from what J.G. says, $\psi_0$ is a Gaussian in the sense of wikipedia, however it is probably the case that your textbook calls Guassians only the ones such that $\int_{\Bbb R}ae^{-(x-b)^2/(2c^2)}\,dx=1$, i.e. the ones such that $\frac a{\lvert c\rvert}=\sqrt{2\pi}$, i.e. the pdfs of some normal distribution with non-zero variance.

Comment: @Gae.S. So the function not squared does not equal one when evaluated through the integral, and thus according to some definitions, it is not considered a Gaussian ? But if we just look at the function without integrating it, it could be seen as one. Is my reasoning correct ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The PDF is $|\psi_0|^2=\frac{1}{a\sqrt{\pi}}\exp\frac{-x^2}{a^2}$, that of an $N(0,\,a^2/2)$ distribution, but $\psi_0$ is not itself a Gaussian PDF. In particular, $\int_{\Bbb R}\psi_0(x)=\pi^{1/4}\sqrt{2a}$.

Comment: But why exactly is it not a gaussian ? When looking on Wikipedia, it seems to me that all prerequistes are fullfilled. There is an exp^(-x^2/over something). What's missing to make it a gaussian ?

Comment: Or is it because only the square of the wavefunction represents a probability distribution like a Gaussian PDF ? Thus, the wavefunction by itself does not represent a probability distribution, and cannot be interpretated as a Gaussian ?

Comment: @holomorphicfunction That's the only explanation I can devise.